# Need Help with Formula(Currency)

Tags: formula

I have a requirement in which I need to create a `Formula(Currency)` field that will multiply a field of type `Formula(Currency)` with a `picklist` containing`percent value.

I am stating fields name & values it contains also I am stating the Formula that I created which is throwing error.

1. Total Revenue - This field is a Formula(Currency)
2. Win Probability - Picklist with Values `20%, 50%, 80%, 100%`

Formula that I tried building was:

```
Total_Revenue__c * VALUE( TEXT(Win_Probability__c ))
```

Comment: I get #Error! as my result in the Formula Field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Oles Malkov answer works perfectly fine

> But requires editing the case statement in the Formula, whenever you add new values to the Picklist and might also look really big if the Picklist has so many values

This **generic formula** will solve that redundancy:

```
 Total_Revenue__c * (VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(Win_Probability__c),'%',''))/100)
```

Comment: I tried both the formula as suggested by @Oles & karthikselva. I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you paste the exact value in Picklist ? you might have space between 20 and % like `20 %`

Comment: These are mine picklist Values: 20%, 50%, 80%, 100%. With no spaces.

Comment: Can you try the updated code in my answer ? I added VALUE around Total_Revenue__c

Comment: Incorrect parameter type for function 'VALUE()'. Expected Text, received Number (Related field: Formula). I got this error when i prefixed Total Revenue with VALUE()

Comment: Its really weird since its already a Number it should have calculated it. Can you check whether Win_Proability__c has value in it. Because I tried the same test in my Org and it actually calculates it perfectly

Comment: I did check for all the values & the return type of the formula is currency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36268/discussion-between-karthikselva-and-guest610).

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert 20% to a number in such way, because it contains non-numeric character - %. Can you try this one:

```
Total_Revenue__c *  CASE( Text(Win_Probability__c ) , '20%', 0.2, '50%', 0.5, '80%', 0.8, '100%', 1, 0)
```